# react-admin ra-data-graphql-simple example and json-graphql-server

Tags: react-admin

I followed the instructions to setup a react-admin + graphql proof-of-concept by using help from here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ra-data-graphql-simple and here - https://github.com/marmelab/json-graphql-server

I'm running the json-graphql-server db.js

I seem to run into issues in getting this working -

```
$ create-react-app test-admin
$ cd test-admin
$ yarn add react-admin
$ yarn add graphql ra-data-graphql-simple
```

I then update App.js with code as shown in the ra-data-graphql-simple example and create posts.js from react-admin tutotial.

On running `yarn start` I get -

```
./src/App.js
 Line 7:  'ApolloClient' is not defined  no-undef
```

Does anyone know how to get the example working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked with the example -

```
import buildGraphQLProvider from 'ra-data-graphql-simple';
import { Admin, Resource, Delete } from 'react-admin';
import { PostCreate, PostEdit, PostList } from './posts';

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { dataProvider: null };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        buildGraphQLProvider({ clientOptions: { uri: 'http://localhost:3000' }})
            .then(dataProvider => this.setState({ dataProvider }));
    }

    render() {
        const { dataProvider } = this.state;

        if (!dataProvider) {
            return <div>Loading</div>;
        }

        return (
            <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
                <Resource name="Post" list={PostList} edit={PostEdit} create={PostCreate} remove={Delete} />
            </Admin>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```